# How do I embed Crossmint NFT payments in a wordpress blog?

Tags: wordpress, payment, checkout, nft, crossmint

I have an NFT collection, and I am trying to sell it from my own Wordpress hosted website.

How can I do this? [Their documentation](https://docs.crossmint.com/docs/payments-introduction) doesn't explain how to add their NFT checkout SDK inside a wordpress blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage this by using the HTML embed block in Wordpress. Here is a code snippet to get you started:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@crossmint/client-sdk-vanilla-ui@1.0.0-alpha.4/lib/index.global.js"></script>
<crossmint-pay-button
  projectId="_PROJECT_ID_"
  collectionId="_COLLECTION_ID_"
  mintConfig='{
    "type": "erc-721",
    "totalPrice": "_PRICE_PER_NFT_"
  }'
  environment="staging"
/>
```

You'll need to add your `projectId` and `collectionId` for your collection, which can be found in the Crossmint Developer Console.

If your mint function accepts an argument for quantity, that should be included in the `mintConfig` object also. For example, if the quantity argument is named `_quantity` then you'd add `"_quantity": "1"` to the `mintConfig`.

Follow the same pattern for any custom mint function arguments, using the name of the argument as the property.

Finally, note the `environment` property. This must match the console you're using.

**staging/testnets:** https://staging.crossmint.com/console

**prod/mainnets:** https://www.crossmint.com/console

Here is a link to a recipe on the Crossmint documentation about this: https://docs.crossmint.com/recipes/adding-the-crossmint-button-to-wordpress-squarespace-webflow